# How does nested brace expansion work in Bash? Specific example: echo 1{a..2{x,z}2}1

Tags: bash, shell

The [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) says that brace expansion can be nested, but doesn't say much more about it. In Bash version 5.1.16 I tried the following

```
$ echo 1{a..2{x,z}2}1
1a..2x21 1a..2z21
```

**How was the output calculated (step-by-step)?** I can't figure it out. I read [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/402318/532792) but couldn't really apply it (properly?) to this specific case.

Comment: What expansion are you expecting to get from that?

Comment: Start by expanding the innermost brace: `2{x,z} ==> 2x 2z`. So your expression becomes `1{a..2x2}1 1{a..2z2}1`. Continue with outer brace `1{a..2x2}1 1{a..2z2}1 ==> 1a..2x21 1a..2z21` because `{a..2x2}` expands as itself (while `{a..c}` would expand as `a b c`).

Comment: @RenaudPacalet But `{a..2x2}` does not expand as itself because it is not a valid sequence expansion. Since it is not a valid brace expansion, it in fact expands as `{a..2x2}`. You can test this with `echo {a..2x2}`.

Comment: @Shawn I don't know what to expect because the manual isn't very clear about how nesting is computed. Note that `echo 1{a2{x,z}2}1` outputs `1{a2x2}1 1{a2z2}1`, which makes sense because the outer braces do not constitute a valid brace expansion, and per the manual "Any incorrectly formed brace expansion is left unchanged. ". However, the inner brace expression is valid, so we get the result by prepending `1{a2` and appending `2}1` to each choice of `x` or `z`.

Comment: @Lilypad: _expands to itself_ is just another way of saying that no expansion is possible and just the whole string is retained.

Comment: Perhaps it is easier to understand, if you do a `echo A{foo{bar,baz}}Z` instead. This is basically like your pattern, just that you have for _foo_ the string _a..2_.

Comment: @user1934428 Note that `echo A{foo{bar,baz}}Z` gives `A{foobar}Z A{foobaz}Z`, but `echo A{a..2{bar,baz}}Z` gives `Aa..2barZ Aa..2bazZ`. The results do not seem analogous. If they were analogous, then `echo A{a..2{bar,baz}}Z` would give `A{a..2bar}Z A{a..2baz}Z`.

Comment: Interesting point. I just found that for comparision, zsh would give the expected _A{a..2bar}Z A{a..2baz}Z_  in this case, but bash doesn't. I can't say whether this is due to a bug in bash, or due to differences between bash and zsh in the definition of brace expansion. Experimenting a bit, I conclude that bash gets let astray by the `..`, which could indicate a range expansion (but of course isn't here).